# What is the geometric representation of a mixed integer second order cone program?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, second-order-cone-programming

Just as the title suggests, what is the geometric representation of a MISOCP? I know a SOCP can be geometrically (or visually) described as a cone... what about a mixed integer second order cone program in a low dimensional space (like 3D)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixed-integer prefix means simply that in your set some coordinates are restricted to be integers. For example this MISOCP

$$
\begin{array}{l}
x\geq \sqrt{y^2+z^2} \\
x = r \\
y,z\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{array}
$$

describes the set of lattice points in a disk of radius $r$.